# Is 「～べくして」 related to 「～べき」 / 「～べく」?

Tags: grammar

How I [understand](http://jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=should#part4) it, `～べく`, meaning `"for the purpose of..." / "In order to...."`, is the conjunctive form of `～べき`, which indicates something that should be done.

> - たくさん本を読む **べき**   (you should read many books)
> - エンジニアになる **べく** 一生懸命勉強した (I studied hard in order to become an engineer)

In the following [example sentence](http://tangorin.com/examples/%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8F%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6), is the `べくして` related grammatically or semantically to `～べき` or `～べく`?

> 起こる **べくして** 起こった事故だった。
>   It was an accident waiting to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rikaichan writes `べくして` as `可くして` and translates it as

> (uk) as it is bound to (happen)/following the natural course
>
> (uk) though possible as it may be

which is derived from `べく` / `～べき`, which are written as `可く` / `～可き`, respectively.